# TheIntern.IO test runner intern-client issues "Attempt to require unloaded module superagent"

Tags: javascript, node.js, dojo, intern

I am trying to run tests with http://theintern.io NODEJS client, however I get the following error:

```
~/WebstormProjects/life-tracker3$ node node_modules/.bin/intern-client config=tests/local.intern reporters=console
Error: **Attempt to require unloaded module superagent**
    at contextRequire (/home/bogdanbiv/WebstormProjects/life-tracker3/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:255:12)
    at req (/home/bogdanbiv/WebstormProjects/life-tracker3/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:30:10)
    at /home/bogdanbiv/WebstormProjects/life-tracker3/tests/api_tests/express.tests.js:5:18
    at Function.vm.runInThisContext (/home/bogdanbiv/WebstormProjects/life-tracker3/node_modules/intern/node_modules/istanbul/lib/hook.js:163:16)
    at /home/bogdanbiv/WebstormProjects/life-tracker3/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:760:8
    at fs.js:268:14
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

Using the same config file local.intern.config, intern-runner opens up the browser and runs all tests gracefully (unit + functional). Of course some tests do fail, but that is to be expected. Full "Intern" configuration is available at http://pastebin.com/c24QPxYE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace indicates that you are calling `require('superagent')` at /home/bogdanbiv/WebstormProjects/life-tracker3/tests/api_tests/express.tests.js:5:18 without actually specifying the superagent module as a dependency, so it fails to load. The `require` function inside Intern tests is the AMD loader’s `require` function, not the Node.js `require` function. See [testing non-AMD code](https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Writing-Tests-with-Intern#testing-non-amd-code) in the documentation for more information on how to load non-AMD dependencies.

Comment: Link has moved to https://theintern.github.io/intern/#testing-commonjs-code and further